# How to access tab control pages outside the tab control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

i have developed a windows form application using c#.

it has a tab control and a menu bar. i want to access a control in tab page when a menu item is clicked.

for example my tab control has 5 tab pages and menu bar has 5 menu items.
when menu item 1 is clicked i want to access the text box within tab page 1.

how to do that?

Comment: try `tabControl.TabPages[0IndexedVal].ControlName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
tabControlName.SelectedIndex = theIndexOfTheTabPage; //switch to the tab page
tabControl1.TabPages[theIndexOfTheTabPage].Controls.Find("textBoxName", true)[0].Select(); //find the TextBox and select it
```

The first line changes to the desired tab page by changing the `SelectedIndex` property of the `tabControl`. The second Line searches for the `TextBox` using the `Find(string name, bool searchAllChildren)` method. Then the `TextBox` is focused by using the `Select()` method.

To click a Button inside a tab use this code:

```
tabControlName.SelectedIndex = theIndexOfTheTabPage; //switch to the tab page
Button b = tabControlName.TabPages[theIndexOfTheTabPage].Controls.Find("buttonName", true)[0] as Button;
b.PerformClick();
```

First get the `Button` the same way as the `TextBox`. Then use `PerformClick()` to click the Button

Comment: and how to access a button in a same way and perform it's click event?
i'm glad if you could help in this also...